# If dropdown is chosen which comes from database, insert data to input values

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to choose a option from the dropdown that has data from the database being inserted into the different input value's. Like if it is loading the information from the database into different input value's
See image - https://ibb.co/nzVn4dg.

After that the user is able to change the input value's

I have googled for information but none answered my question. There were alot of static code with answers but i need it to be dynamic. It could be as much as 20 dropdown options or it could be just 3 options.

```
<select name="concert" class="form-control">

<?php

while ( $row = $concertResult->fetch() )
   {
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">Id: '.$row['id'].' 
Artiest naam: '.$row['artiestnaam'].' Locatie: '.$row['locatie']. ' 
Evenement: '.$row['evenement'].'</option>';

 }

?>
  </select>
```

If you saw the above image then you can see that you can choose an option from the dropdown field. The option contains the artist name(Drake) and Location(Amsterdam). I want these values being inserted inside the input value's of "Artist name" and "Location". And also the rest ofcourse.

I am curious how it could work.

Thank you for your time i appreciate it.

Comment: you would need to use JavaScript to handle the "change" event of the `<select` element. Then you can get the selected text, and extract the values from that text (you might need a regular expression, since the text format is not very well delimited). Lastly you can set the values of each textbox to be the extracted values.

Comment: But I'm not really sure why you need to do any of that? If the user selects an item from the dropdown, then based on its ID you already know what artist name and location they chose, because that info is already associated with the concert record. So you can just submit that selected ID back to the server to understand what the user chose. I don't see any advantage to splitting that data into separate textboxes, when it's information you already hold in your database. If you put it into a textbox it just gives the user an opportunity to change it, which probably isn't what you want?

Comment: If you _are_ wanting the user to edit the concert details, then what you should be doing is letting them select the concert from a list, which then sends a request (maybe AJAX) to the server to get the specific details of that concert as a proper object with individual properties for each field (rather than a jumbled string) which can then be used easily to populate the form fields for editing. That's the normal way of doing it. Your approach is unconventional and not making life easy for yourself.

Comment: @ADyson Oke Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', 'select[name="concert"]', function() {
    var concert_value = jQuery(this).val();
    var artiestnaam = concert_value.match("Artiest naam: (.*) Locatie");
    var locatie = concert_value.match("Locatie: (.*) Evenement");
    var evenement = concert_value.match("Evenement: (.*)");
    /**
     * Then you can put values into input like jQuery('#input_id').val(artiestnaam);
     */
})
```

Comment: Can you add how the input field should look in html

Comment: Your input should have name or id, just use that to put the values into it.
For example, input should be like this <input type="text" name="artiestnaam" id="artiestnaam" />

Comment: Oke i will test it later, i will let you know. Thank you

Comment: I put the jquery code in the footer and the html code like you said above but it doesnt work. I don't understand, can you edit your answer more specific

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the form here? So that I can give you more exact jQuery code to make it work.

Comment: I already fixed some code with a tutorial. It works now, thank you